# Echo в массиве php

Tags: php

Как разом вывести все значения из массива? Не хочется много раз писать echo

```js
$massive[] = 'a';        
$massive[] = 1 ;         
$massive[] = 2;

echo $massive[0];
echo $massive[1];
echo $massive[2];
```

Comment: У тебя уже есть вопросы где ты работаешь с массивами и циклы тоже...Довольно странно спрашивать вопрос, ответ на который ты уже реализовывал несколько раз

Comment: Там массивов не было. Там циклы без массивов. Я только что начал изучать массивы в php

Comment: Ты в цикле делал echo. К массиву применяется цикл ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $array = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'];
  $arrayLength = count($array);
  $x = 0;
  $y = 0;
```

## Foreach

```
foreach($array as $key => $item){
  echo $item;
}
```

## For

```
for($i = 0; $i < $arrayLength; $i++){
  echo $array[$i];
}
```

## While

```
while($x < $arrayLength){
  echo $array[$x];
  $x++;
}
```

## Do While

```
do{
  echo $array[$y];
  $y++;
 }
 while($y < $arrayLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

Выводите каждый элемент в цикле [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach ($massive as $element) {
    echo $element;
}
```

Или соедините все элементы массива в строку при помощи функции [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.implode):

```
$str = implode('', $massive);
echo $str;
```

Answer (score -1):

Лучше конечно выводите массивы через var_dump($array);

но у вас там и массивов то нет) Массив это когда так:

```
// пример массива
$array = [11,22,33,44,55];

// Теперь можете обратиться к любому элементу  этого
echo $array[0]; // Выведет вам первый элемент массива, то есть "11"
echo $array[3]; // Выведет вам четвертый элемент массива, то есть "44"
```